# Display a message from Api as a notification

Tags: android, json, api, notifications

I got a text from my Api and i want to display it as a notification.How can i do that?Here is the code which i have the notification code and the code that getting the json object.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pushnotifications);
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =   new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background) // notification icon
            .setContentTitle("Notification!") // title for notification
            .setContentText("Hello word"); // message for notification

    Notification mNotificationManager = mBuilder.build();
    NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).notify(0,mNotificationManager);

    URL obj = null;
    try {
        obj = new URL("https://gekon.technologypark.cz/api/v1/notification/demo/8");
        HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("ApiSecret", LoginInfo.ApiSecret);
        conn.connect();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String output;
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null)
            sb.append(output);

        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(sb.toString());

        String notifText=(String) jsonObj.get("data");

        Log.d("log","PUSH NANI"+notifText);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("log","PUSH CATCG"+e);

    }

}
```

Comment: if you are testing on device android 8 and above you need to configure notification channel.

Comment: @KaranMer i know but i'm testing it on android 7

Comment: you need to use random id inside `notify()` as using duplicate id would override your notification

Answer (score 1):

Call your notification code inside api success, have look

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pushnotifications);


    URL obj = null;
    try {
        obj = new URL("https://gekon.technologypark.cz/api/v1/notification/demo/8");
        HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("ApiSecret", LoginInfo.ApiSecret);
        conn.connect();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String output;
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null)
            sb.append(output);

        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(sb.toString());

        String notifText=(String) jsonObj.get("data");

        Log.d("log","PUSH NANI"+notifText);
         showNotification(notiftext)


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("log","PUSH CATCG"+e);

    }

}
```

here is the method for show notification after successful api call.

```
public void showNotification(String message){
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =   new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background) // notification icon
                .setContentTitle("Notification!") // title for notification
                .setContentText(message); // message for notification

       NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
       NotificationManager.notify().
      mNotificationManager.notify(001, mBuilder.build());
}
```

Hope it will help you!!

Comment: Thanks for the answer!For a strange reason it doesn't show any notification :/

Comment: @AlexKolydas i edited the code, please check it once again!

Comment: Still nothing :/ I deleted NotificationManager.notify(). because i believed it was a mistake right?

Comment: `Log.d("log","PUSH NANI"+notifText);` what does its printing ?

Comment: My text from api

Comment: which api version you are using ?

Comment: What do you mean?(Sorry new programmer) it's version 1 as it says in the api's documentation

Comment: i mean what target version you set in app.gradle file

Comment: On       `       NotificationManager.notify().` it says that notify is not static and it cant be in static context.But i don't see any static context

Comment: targetSdkVersion 27

Comment: that's why its not showing, you have to use notification channel, try to google it.